# Create Dummy Var by two Groups if logical=TRUE across two Dataframes in R

Tags: r, data.table

We have two data frames. `station_data` contains weather observations at the geography-day level. `tavg_monthly` contains the quantiles of `tvag` at the geography-month level. We want to create a dummy variable equal to `TRUE` if the observation in `station_data` is greater or equal to the 75% percentile or smaller than the 25% percentile (stored in `tavg_monthly` as `tavg_monthly$75%` or `tavg_monthly$75%`) indicating "extreme weather". Observations are grouped by `fips` and `month`.

*Example station_data*:

```
 structure(list(fips = c("01073", "01073", "01073", "01073", "01073", 
 "01073"), rain = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), year = c("1980", "1980", 
 "1980", "1980", "1980", "1980"), week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L), month = c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"), day = c("001", 
 "002", "003", "004", "005", "006"), tavg = c(3.32500010728836, 
 4.64999985694885, 7.77500009536743, 4.3125, 0, 1.86249995231628
 )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Example prcp_monthly*:

```
 structure(list(fips = c("01073", "01073", "01073", "01073", "01073", 
 "01073"), month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"), 
 `25%` = c(2.68333338201046, 
 4.65000009536743, 8.86249977350235, 13.8229166865349, 18.7999997138977, 
 23.7364585399628), `75%` = c(9.79999996721745, 12.1333334445953, 
 16.3260417580605, 20.1833333969116, 23.6843748092651, 26.5312495231628
 ), n = c(1116L, 1017L, 1116L, 1080L, 1116L, 1080L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the following line

```
setDT(station_data)[, extr_tavg_monthly := station_data$tavg>=prcp_monthly$`75%` | output$tavg<=input$`25%` , by = list(fips, month)]
```

I get an extra column with results, however, they are inconsistent (i.e. sometimes wrong). I receive over 50 warnings of the form

```
In `[.data.table`(setDT(station_data), , `:=`(extr_prcp_monthly,  ...:
RHS 1 is length (greater than the size (1116) of group 25). The 
last 35868 element(s) will be discarded.
```

where 35868 / 12 months = 3082 (number of my geographical units) and 1116 obs. =  36 years of data * 31 days (e.g. in January) in the full data set.

The result is:

```
    fips rain year week month day   tavg extr_tavg_monthly
1: 01073    0 1980    1    01 001 3.3250             FALSE
2: 01073    0 1980    1    01 002 4.6500              TRUE
3: 01073    0 1980    1    01 003 7.7750              TRUE
4: 01073    0 1980    1    01 004 4.3125              TRUE
5: 01073    0 1980    1    01 005 0.0000              TRUE
6: 01073    0 1980    1    01 006 1.8625              TRUE
```

It should be however,

```
   fips rain year week month day   tavg extr_tavg_monthly
1: 01073    0 1980    1    01 001 3.3250              FALSE
2: 01073    0 1980    1    01 002 4.6500              FALSE
3: 01073    0 1980    1    01 003 7.7750              FALSE
4: 01073    0 1980    1    01 004 4.3125              FALSE
5: 01073    0 1980    1    01 005 0.0000              TRUE
6: 01073    0 1980    1    01 006 1.8625              TRUE
```

given that the quartiles for `month=01` and `fips=01073` are

```
   fips month      25% 75%    n
1 01073    01 2.683333 9.8 1116
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, this can be solved using a "non-equi update join":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(station_data)[setDT(prcp_monthly), 
             on = .(fips, month, tavg >= `25%`, tavg < `75%`), 
             extr_tavg_monthly := FALSE][
               is.na(extr_tavg_monthly), extr_tavg_monthly := TRUE][]
```

> ```
>     fips rain year week month day   tavg extr_tavg_monthly
> 1: 01073    0 1980    1    01 001 3.3250             FALSE
> 2: 01073    0 1980    1    01 002 4.6500             FALSE
> 3: 01073    0 1980    1    01 003 7.7750             FALSE
> 4: 01073    0 1980    1    01 004 4.3125             FALSE
> 5: 01073    0 1980    1    01 005 0.0000              TRUE
> 6: 01073    0 1980    1    01 006 1.8625              TRUE
> ```

Please, note that besides `extr_tavg_monthly` no other columns have been added to the station dataset. This is in contrast to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733355/3817004) which adds also the `25%` and `75%` columns to `station_data`.

#### Edit

If I understand correctly from OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732429/create-dummy-var-by-two-groups-if-logical-true-across-two-dataframes-in-r/53802782#comment94481914_53802782), it is required that `extr_tavg_monthly` should be `NA` in case `tavg` is missing. This can be achieved by a slight modification.

```
# create 2nd dataset by appending an additional row containing NA
station_data2 <- rbind(setDT(station_data), station_data[.N])
station_data2[.N, `:=`(day = "007", tavg = NA)]
station_data2
```

> ```
>     fips rain year week month day   tavg
> 1: 01073    0 1980    1    01 001 3.3250
> 2: 01073    0 1980    1    01 002 4.6500
> 3: 01073    0 1980    1    01 003 7.7750
> 4: 01073    0 1980    1    01 004 4.3125
> 5: 01073    0 1980    1    01 005 0.0000
> 6: 01073    0 1980    1    01 006 1.8625
> 7: 01073    0 1980    1    01 007     NA
> ```

```
station_data2[setDT(prcp_monthly), 
              on = .(fips, month, tavg >= `25%`, tavg < `75%`), 
              extr_tavg_monthly := FALSE][
                is.na(extr_tavg_monthly) & !is.na(tavg), extr_tavg_monthly := TRUE]
station_data2
```

> ```
>     fips rain year week month day   tavg extr_tavg_monthly
> 1: 01073    0 1980    1    01 001 3.3250             FALSE
> 2: 01073    0 1980    1    01 002 4.6500             FALSE
> 3: 01073    0 1980    1    01 003 7.7750             FALSE
> 4: 01073    0 1980    1    01 004 4.3125             FALSE
> 5: 01073    0 1980    1    01 005 0.0000              TRUE
> 6: 01073    0 1980    1    01 006 1.8625              TRUE
> 7: 01073    0 1980    1    01 007     NA                NA
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Uwe. While being technically correct this method would, however, ignore missing values in the raw data and substitute `NA` with `TRUE`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @cg89x, I have modified my answer to cover the additional requirement concerning missing `tavg` values.

Answer (score 0):

What works is merging in the quartiles, so I guess the reason comes from the missmatch in length as given in the warning messages.

```
setDT(station_data)[setDT(tavg_monthly), `25%` := `25%`, on=c("fips", "month")]
setDT(station_data)[setDT(tavg_monthly), `75%` := `75%`, on=c("fips", "month")]
setDT(station_data)[, extr_tavg_monthly :=tavg>=`75%` | tavg<=`25%`, by = list(fips, month)]
```